# JmsTemplate with CachingConnectionFactory Connection Recovery for IBM MQ Queue

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I am connecting to two IBM MQ servers from a same client using JmsTemplate.

I have configured JmsTemplate's reconnectOnException as well as IBM MQ connection factory's setClientReconnectOptions.

Spring bean definition:

```
<bean id="firstMQCachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="firstMQConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="20" /> 
        <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="secondMQCachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="secondMQConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="20" /> 
        <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Set IBM MQ reconnect options:

```
firstMQConnectionFactory.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstancs.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT;
firstMQConnectionFactory.setClientReconnectTimeout(5);
secondMQConnectionFactory.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstancs.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT;
secondMQConnectionFactory.setClientReconnectTimeout(5);
```

This is how I am sending message:

```
public boolean sendMsg(final String content) throws JmsException{
    boolean success = false;
    LOGGER.info("sendMsg: Start ") ;
    try { 
        jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(content);
                textMessage.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_CHARACTER_SET,  "UTF8");
                textMessage.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_ENCODING,
                        WMQConstants.WMQ_ENCODING_NATIVE);
                textMessage.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
                return textMessage;
            }
        });
        LOGGER.info("sendMsg: Message sent to MQ successfully");
        success = true;
    } catch (JmsException je) {
        LOGGER.error("sendMsg: JmsException " + je.getMessage());
        throw je;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        LOGGER.error("sendMsg: Exception message: " + exc.getMessage());
        throw exc;
    }
    return success; 
}
```

When none of the connections is being used during low system load, a broken connection to first system is detected by Spring.

```
18 Nov 2017 20:41:03,924 WARN CachingConnectionFactory:322 - Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred.
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
18 Nov 2017 20:41:03,940 DEBUG CachingConnectionFactory:486 - Closing cached Session: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession@4cbb56ac
18 Nov 2017 20:41:04,006 DEBUG CachingConnectionFactory:447 - Closing shared JMS Connection: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection@48d23557
18 Nov 2017 20:41:04,008 DEBUG CachingConnectionFactory:463 - Could not close shared JMS Connection
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0019: Failed to disconnect from queue manager 'QM1' using connection mode '1' and host name 'system1.company.com(62305)'.
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'system1.company.com/10.0.0.1:62305 (system1.company.com)'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=system1.company.com/10.0.0.1:62305 (system1.company.com),4=TCP]
```

This somehow affects JmsTemplate connection to second system and when used I get an exception with no message.

```
18 Nov 2017 23:43:40,247 DEBUG JmsTemplate:482 - Executing callback on JMS Session: Cached JMS Session: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession@5a4a62d0
18 Nov 2017 23:43:40,248 DEBUG JmsTemplate:595 - Sending created message: 
18 Nov 2017 23:43:40,251 ERROR MessageSender:86 - sendMsg: Exception message: null
```

Stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.checkIfDisconnected(RemoteSession.java:249)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiPutMessageWithProps(RemoteFAP.java:9045)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiPut(RemoteFAP.java:8115)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiPut(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:624)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiPut(ESEJMQI.java:635)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$SpiIdentifiedProducerShadow.sendInternal(WMQMessageProducer.java:864)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$ProducerShadow.send(WMQMessageProducer.java:548)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.send(WMQMessageProducer.java:1393)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendMessage(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:851)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.synchronousSendInternal(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:2051)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendInternal(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:1989)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.send(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:1569)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:321)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachedMessageProducer.send(CachedMessageProducer.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor120.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachedMessageProducer$Jms2MessageProducerInvocationHandler.invoke(CachedMessageProducer.java:293)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.send(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:626)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:597)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$3.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:562)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:484)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:559)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:550)
```

- Why does broken connection for one CachingConnectionFactory affect
  another?
- Why does second connection not recover from 'Exception' once
  it detects it?
- Do I need to wrap Exception in JmsException for spring jms to detect it?

Comment: >`sendMsg: Exception message: null` I suggest you print the full stack trace and edit the question to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create the error by changing network connections.

When IBM MQ client's reconnect is turned on and network is changed, it automatically refreshes connections under the hood. Spring JMS wouldn't always realize this refresh and put me into state where connections in one CachingConnectionFactory would be refreshed but not for other.

I turned off IBM MQ clients reconnect by not setting setClientReconnectOptions and let spring handle all the connection changes and issues. This fixed the above error.